# string is not same in Python3x as for Python2.x but Still it is working

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am confused with the strings in Python,

Consider this code,

```
fo = open("test.txt", "wb")
fo.write(bytes('Sufiyan','UTF-8'))
```

If I were to run this code, It would give this error,

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "C:\Users\Sufiyan\Desktop\AES\a.py", line 2, in <module>
>
>     fo.write('Sufiyan')
>
> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
> ```

Therefore, I have to convert it into `bytes` and provide the encoding type.

```
fo = open("test.txt", "wb")
fo.write(bytes('Sufiyan','UTF-8'))
```

This works, because If you use Python3x then string is not the same type as for Python 2.x, you must cast it to bytes (encode it).

Now, When I am using this code to write to a file,

```
def BB_cf(file, *args, **kwargs): #Create files
    
    try:
        
        fo = open(file)
        fo.close()
        
    except IOError:

        print (file, 'not Found')
        print ("Creating file.....")
        fo = open(file, "w")
        print (file,"Created Successfully!")
        
        if file == 'input_Data.txt':
            print(file,"is Empty..\nWriting Data..")
            text = kwargs.get('text', None)
            fo.write(text)
            print("'"+text+"'", "is written in",file)
            fo.close()
            
        fo.close()
```

.

```
BB_cf('input_Data.txt', text='Sufiyan Ghori')
```

As you can see in the 4th last line, `fo.write(text)`, I haven't encoded it, but the code is still working.

Why the code is working without encoding it ?

Now if I cast it to `bytes`, It will give the following error,

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\Sufiyan\Desktop\AES\BlackBox.py", line 47, in
>
> ```
> BB_cf('input_Data.txt', text='Sufiyan Ghori')   File
> ```
>
> "C:\Users\Sufiyan\Desktop\AES\BlackBox.py", line 41, in BB_cf
>
> ```
> fo.write(bytes(text,'UTF-8')) TypeError: must be str, not bytes
> ```

Both the above codes are running using Python3x,
The first one wants me to encode the `string` into `Bytes` while the 2nd one is running without encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time around, you open your file by doing `fo = open("test.txt", "wb")`. The second time, you do `fo = open(file, "w")`. The string `"wb"` indicates to Python that you want to write to the file using only bytes, instead of strings, whereas the string `"w"` in your second example states the reverse.

Specifically, the documentation for the [open](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function states:

> As mentioned in the Overview, **Python distinguishes between binary and text I/O**. Files opened in binary mode (including 'b' in the mode argument) **return contents as bytes objects** without any decoding. In text mode (the default, or when 't' is included in the mode argument), **the contents of the file are returned as str**, the bytes having been first decoded using a platform-dependent encoding or using the specified encoding if given.

(emphasis added by me)

Comment: I see that, But If I first convert the string into bytearray and write it into the file with "wb" , shouldn't it work then too without encoding it into bytes?

Comment: @Xufyan: Yes, it should. Does this not actually work or something? The only difference between `bytes` and `bytearray` is that the latter is mutable (you can write into it). They both have the same byte-level contents.